# How do I set data for subgrid in expandable grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

My array is like this

`$scope.ebObjArr = [{key: 'val', monthsArray: [{myDate:'',}]},{myDate:'',}]`

`monthArray` is used for filling the sub-grid. I can't figure out how to set data for the sub-grid.

I tried this:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < $scope.ebObjArr.length; i++) {
    $scope.ebObjArr.monthsArray[i].subGridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [{ name: "Month", field: "myDate" }, { name: "Cost", field: "totalCost" }, {name:"Units consumed", field : "unitsConsumed"}],
        data: $scope.ebObjArr[i].monthsArray
    }
}
```

I tried this too :

for (let i = 0; i < $scope.ebObjArr.length; i++) {

```
                for (let j = 0; j < $scope.ebObjArr[i].monthsArray[j].length; j++) {
                    $scope.ebObjArr[i].monthsArray[j].subGridOptions = {
                        columnDefs: [{ name: "Month", field: "myDate" }, { name: "Cost", field: "totalCost" }, { name: "Units consumed", field: "unitsConsumed" }],
                        data: $scope.ebObjArr[i].monthsArray[j]
                    }
                }


            }
```

I'm using only the `MainCtrl` in this example: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this but since no one answered I did this and it worked.

```
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
        $scope.grid1Api.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function (row) {
            if (row.isExpanded) {
                console.log(row.entity);
                row.entity.subGridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: [{ name: "Month", field: "myDate" }, { name: "Cost", field: "totalCost" }, { name: "Units consumed", field: "unitsConsumed" }],
                }
                row.entity.subGridOptions.data = (function () {
                    var a;

                         a = $scope.ebObjArr.filter(function (val) {
                            if (val.ebName === row.entity.ebName && val.ebAddress === row.entity.ebAddress) {
                               // console.log(val.monthsArray);
                                return val.monthsArray
                            }
                            return false;
                         });
                         console.log(a);
                    console.log(a[0].monthsArray);
                    return a[0].monthsArray;
                })();
                console.log(row.entity.subGridOptions.data);
            }

        });
    }
```